# Rails 5 redirect notice style

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user creates a ticket my site redirects to the ticket and displays a notice that informs the user it has been created. At the moment it is a standard notice with no styling.

This is the block that redirects - I need to add a class to the notice. How can this be achieved?

```
redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a class to a tag, maybe a `div`, and then wrap your `notice` there, like:

```
<div class="notice">
  <%= notice %>
</div>
```

But what's usually done, is to assign a class to the html tag dinamycally, this way if the flash message is `notice` or other, then you have the styles defined for each of them, like:

```
<% flash.each do |key, message| %> 
  <p class="<%= key %>">
    <%= message %>
  </p> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

In rails 5 you can use 'add_flash_types' method. Just add it to ApplicationController and include the types you want:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  add_flash_types :success, :warning, :danger, :info
```

on your controller use the appropriate type instead of 'notice':

```
redirect_to @ticket, success: 'Ticket was successfully created.'
```

and then you can automate your view:

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>">
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

source:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Flash/ClassMethods.html#method-i-add_flash_types

Comment: From the docs: "This method will automatically define a new method for each of the given names, and it will be available in your views" so you can then call `success`, etc. in your views.